# How to copy .gitignore file to the archetype JAR?

Tags: java, maven, archetypes

I'm trying to include the `.gitignore` file to the jar. I tried everything but it still not copying the `.gitignore` file. Here is my resources and jar plugins

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <includes>.gitignore</includes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I even tried `maven-resources-plugin` with `3.1.0`, but it's not adding? How to achieve it?

Comment: What if you'll put your `.gitignore`  into the `main/resources` directory? or even into the `main/resources/my/package/name/.gitignore`  ?

Comment: Why do you like to put the `.gitignore` into a jar file? That does not make sense... Please explain more in detail...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, I'm creating the boilerplate for java. In that I'm specifying everything needed to create a maven project. For that I also need to put `.gitignore`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven-resources-plugin won't copy .metadata folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422298/maven-resources-plugin-wont-copy-metadata-folder)

Comment: First that will not work that work...furthermore there are so called archetypes for that...

Comment: @Bharat The _. gitignore_ file tells Git which files to ignore when committing your project to the GitHub repository. This is the purpose of this file. There is absolutely no reason whatsoever why you would need this file in a JAR file. All you need to do is check in the _.gitignore_ file in your project so that everyone working on it has the same version. When you build your JAR, the _.gitignore_ should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Archetype jars are created by the archetype plugin. So you have to configure that by setting the [`useDefaultExcludes`](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/jar-mojo.html#useDefaultExcludes) to false:

```xml
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Note that the configuration key is called `useDefaultExcludes` as opposed to `addDefaultExcludes` for resources plugin.

I don't know why people are saying it doesn't make sense to add `.gitignore` to an archetype jar. I find it very useful to make sure `target/` and the like are automatically ignored.